# I can't read the file line by line and get line as list

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

What is wrong in this code

```
set fid [open "file_name" a+]
while {[gets $fid line] > -1} {
    lappend short_keys_list [lindex $line 5]
    puts  $line 
}
close $fid
# while loop not working
```

Comment: What do you want it to do, and in what way does it fail to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Since you have opened the file with `a+` mode, the file pointer is set to the end of the file. Due to this, the call to `gets $fid line` is returning -1 as it has nothing to read from the file and causing the while loop to terminate.

Try this

```
set fid [open "file_name" r]
```

**Reference :**  [open](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/open.htm#M10)

Answer (score 1):

You've been answered with a couple of hints to what isn't working. The best solution to what you seem to be doing, however, is this:

```
foreachLine line file_name {
    lappend short_keys_list [lindex $line 5]
    puts $line
}
```

This invocation takes care of opening and closing of the file, reading each line of the file and storing it in the variable name you've provided (`line` in this case) and calling your script once for each line. For this to work you first need to get the `fileutil` package ready:

```
package require fileutil
namespace import ::fileutil::*
```

The `fileutil` package contains a lot of useful commands to easily deal with issues that are a major bother when using low-level filehandling, as I'm usually quick to point out `#heyhoodiecrowwhydontyoumarryfileutilalready`.

Documentation: [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html) package, [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [namespace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm)